# Regex pattern for date

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I have the following String:

```
vitals.date_created==2013-7-3 11:23:32
```

I am using the regex

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[$.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+[><=]=?[a-z0-9A-Z'\\.@- ]+
```

but the regex doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You are creating a character range in the last [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and this is in the wrong order (error on some systems)

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[$.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+[><=]=?[a-z0-9A-Z'\\.@- ]+
                                                          ^^^
   ```

   I assume you don't want a range of characters here, so escape the dash or move it to the end:

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[$.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+[><=]=?[a-z0-9A-Z'\\.@ -]+
   ```
2. The time in your string has colons, your last character class hasn't. How should it match? Just add them to the class:

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[$.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+[><=]=?[a-z0-9A-Z'\\.@: -]+
   ```

**See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?35u73)**

Comment: I did this and it works:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[$.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+[><=]=?[a-z0-9A-Z'\.@\-\: ]+"